# Re-rendering SVGs from the cache. Recomputed or remembered?

Tags: caching, browser, svg

I can't find an answer to this question, when the browser takes an SVG from the cache does it re-compute the xml or not, does it store the 'IMAGE' that it has already created? (How?)

I would've have thought not, but then I've noticed how fast repeated svgs load.

I've also noticed slowness on a page logo (in mobile browsers) which make me think THEY re-compute the SVG, so i've moved to PNG's (which are obviously cached) for mobile to save a lot of computational work for the low end phones.

So maybe, does the answer depend on the browser / browser type / browser settings?

*my svg's are compressed svgz's by the way

Comment: This would depend heavily on one particular browser implementation. As far as a know the w3 recommendation doesn't insist on any caching whatsoever---it's just concerned with presentation.

Comment: @bitmask Thx, if anyone has any links to recommendations vis-a-vis caching svg best practices across browsers i'd be very grateful...

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes it does and sometimes it doesn't. Most browsers go to some effort not to rerender things unless they have to. There is a [buffered-rendering](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/single-page.html#painting-BufferedRenderingProperty) property in SVG 1.2 Tiny that may help if you're using Opera, other browsers try to do things automatically without requiring such hints though.

Browsers generally don't cache SVG content as a simple bitmap though. They do cache things like the absolute position and size of shapes and text with transforms applied, the css tree structure, gradients etc and then use this information they can redraw the content much more quickly than having to work it out each repaint. Such information allows browsers to copy with javascript and SMIL animation of parts of the SVG content as well as user scrolling.

Comment: Thanks Robert, but they always do render the images though right? The browser can't 'hold' an image can it? So any speed advantage is from not downloading, is that about right?

Comment: What do you mean by doing things automatically, determine if it is dynamic/static as per the SVG 1.2 Tiny specs? Can I help the browser decide?

Comment: I mean browsers look to see what part of the content (be that SVG, HTML or MathML) is changing either via javascript or animation and which is not. They draw the dynamic parts and static parts separately and then compose each bit. They don't need developers of content to mark the content in any way to do this. See https://wiki.mozilla.org/Gecko:Layers for Firefox though other browsers do similar things.

Comment: Opera does automatic caching of certain things just like the other browsers. In most scenarios you don't need to use the buffered-rendering hint though it can help in some cases where you know your content and target device well.

Comment: robert + @erik, thanks guys but I'm still left wondering what is the browser caching/part-caching? the xml to recompute or an image to re-show? Maybe my basic understanding is flawed but would a browser only need to compute a complicated SVG once and then just 'reshow', really?

Comment: Browsers do cache the xml and also information derived from the xml but that intermediate information isn't a bitmap, it's shortcut information that enables the xml to be displayed more quickly.

Answer (score -1):

Can you use two elements as a buffer where you update attributes and call [replaceChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild) from parent. E.g.

```js
// create and append elements first
var draft // the element which will be rendered next
var drawn // the element which is currently visible

function renderLoop(parent) {
  const previous = drawn
  const current = draw(draft) // update draft element attributes here
  parent.replaceChild(current, previous) // null & isConnected checks omitted
  drawn = current
  draft = previous // Reuse existing element
}
```