# Programmatically reload a SVG file

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, browser-cache

I have a Javascript/jQuery function that creates/overwrites a SVG file, which is embedded in a page in a web app. I made sure that, each time this function is called, the SVG file is updated, but under some occasions (which I am not sure when), the SVG file seems to be cached in the web browser, and does not appear as updated. What is the best way to ensure that the SVG file is rendered with the new content each time this function is called?

Comment: This might be of some help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13057034/re-rendering-svgs-from-the-cache-recomputed-or-remembered

Comment: If you're loading the SVG file from a url, you can try appending a different query string suffix to its path each time you fetch it, e.g. '/path/to/file.svg?t=1546598249526' where t could be the current timestamp. This may help you invalidate browser caching for that resource.